# Unsure on how this element works?

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a question for my maths class that I'm confused by. I need to sketch a graph with the equation f(t) = 2 cos(πt), t ∈ [0, 2].

I know the Amplitude equals 2 and that the Period is 2*π over t. But I don't understand how to get the value of t. I've understand elements but I just don't understand this one at all.

Answer (score 1):

You understood it wrong! $\frac{2\pi}{t}$ cannot be the period, as $t$ is your actual variable! However:

$$f(t+n) = 2 \cos(\pi(t+n)) = 2 \cos(\pi t +n\pi)$$

Does this suggest you something about what $n$ is the period?